# PhantomJS change webpage content before evaluating

Tags: dom, phantomjs

I'd like to either remove an HTML element or simply remove first N characters of a webpage before evaluating/rendering it.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what stops you from processing the page as it is?

Comment: The page wants to be called from an iframe, so I need to remove that piece of JS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on multiple scenarios. I will only outline the steps for each combination of the answers to the following questions.

1. Is the piece of JS called onload (**ol**) or is the script block immediately evaluated (**ie**)?
2. Is it an inline script (**is**) or is the script loaded separately (src attribute) (**ls**)?
3. Does the script block also contain some code that should not be removed (**nr**) or can it be removed completely (**rc**)?

#### 1. Script is loaded separately (ls) & code can be removed completely (rc)

Register to the `onResourceRequested` listener and `request.abort()` depending on the matched url.

#### 2. Script is loaded separately (ls) & contains other code too (nr)

This can only be done when the following code blocks do not depend on the code that should not be removed (which is unlikely). This is most likely necessary for click events that are registered in the DOM.

In this case cancel the request like in **1.**, download the script through an XHR, remove the unwanted code parts and add code block to the DOM. For this to work, you would need to disable web security, because otherwise no resource can be requested if it is not on the same domain: `--web-security=false`.

#### 3. Script is loaded with the DOM (is) & JS executed through `onload` (ol) & can be removed completely (rc)

*This is probably very error prone.* You would begin an Interval with `setInterval(function(){}, 5)` from a [`page.onInitialized`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-initialized.html) callback. Inside the interval you would need to check if `window.onload` (or something else you can get your hands on) is set in the page context. You remove it, if it is indeed the function that you wanted to remove by checking `window.onload.toString().match(/something/)`.

This can be done directly and completely inside the page context (inside `page.evaluate`).

#### 4. Script is loaded with the DOM (is) & JS executed through `onload` (ol) & contains other code too (nr)

Begin like in **3.**, but instead of removing `window.onload`, you can do

```
eval("window.onload = " + window.onload.toString().replace(/something/,''))
```

#### 5. Script is loaded with the DOM (is) & the script block immediately evaluated (ie)

You can load the page as an XHR, replace the text and apply the adjusted content to the page. This will essentially be a filled `about:blank` page. For this to work, you would need to disable web security, because otherwise no resource can be requested if it is not on the same domain: `--web-security=false` or `--local-to-remote-url-access=true`. This would also work for **3.** and **4.**.

There is still one problem though. Pages don't use full URLs most of the time. So when a script or element refers to `stuff.php` PhantomJS cannot request it. When the `page.content` is set then the page URL is essentially about:blank and all requests with incomplete URLs point to `file:///...`. Obviously there are no such files. Those resources must be replaced with their full URL counterparts.
There are three types of such URLs:

- `//example.com/resource.php` variable protocol
- `/resource.php` variable protocol and domain
- `resource.php` variable protocol, domain and path to resource

Complete example:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    url = 'http://www.example.com';

page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var content = page.evaluate(function(url){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", url, false);
            xhr.send();
            return xhr.responseText;
        }, url);
        page.render("test_example.png");
        page.content = content.replace(/xample/g,"asy");
        page.render("test_easy.png");
        console.log("url "+page.url); // about:blank
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

You might want to look into proper manipulation techniques apart from the simple string replace.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It's an inline script located in the header, therefor it's unfortunately option 5. What do you mean by "script specific things"? The code there is if (top === self) { document.location.href = ""; }

Comment: Ok, 5. is possible even without script specific knowledge. I will edit as soon as possible.

Comment: Very original solution. When you ran the code, didn't you get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery" error? I also tried page.injectJs('jquery.min.js'); and put the file in the script folder, but it didn't help either.

Comment: If you use jQuery in the page context, then you need to [inject](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#webpage-injectJs) it first. The snippet is just an sample script running on example.com. See what it does without modification first and then modify to your case.

Comment: +1 Thank you for great answer. And to add something perhaps obvious: For 5., if it's not online critical, xhr part and web security can be made away with `var repl_content = page.content.replace("say","asy");` then printing/showing/rendering `repl_content` instead.

Comment: @Efreet Theoretically, this should work, but there are instances of pages which remove script blocks after they are executed in which case this would not work correctly. Also, I forgot something crucial for 5.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this, but any idea how you would do option 5 for any subsequent page redirects too?

Comment: @Paraknight Redirects are very tricky, because there are many different variants. You can start logging with the `page.onNavigationRequested`, `page.onResourceRequested`, `page.onLoadStarted` and `page.onUrlChanged`. You can log when these events are fired and then find a trigger condition when a replacement should be run from one of these events.

Comment: Since setting the page content simply with `page.content = "some HTML string"` also sets the URL to "about:blank", this will likely break some sites. It would be preferable to use `page.setContent("some HTML string", page.url)`.

Comment: step 4 will create second onload

Comment: @FlashThunder My tests show that only one callback is kept. The initial one - if available - will be overwritten.

Comment: @ArtjomB. hmm... maybe you are right, but only if it's from the same scope, but doesn't work in real life example, when it was defined from other scope. Had a great problem with a translator to delay translation, and the solution given in this answer did not work. It just stacked events. Can give you real code, but not publicly. You will see what I mean.